# How do I customize Google Cloud Datalab with extra Python modules?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'd like to install zipline, the python module for financial backtesting, onto a Google Cloud Datalab instance. What's the best way to do this?

(I tried to move the VM to user managed and SSH in, but it wouldn't let SSH in).

(Also tried %%bash pip install zipline, which almost worked save for version conflicts, but not sure if this is a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the %bash pip install option is the only one supported. We should have better customization capability coming quite soon.

Comment: Is it possible to SSH in and make changes directly if user managed?